# Why is my table view only showing about 20 of my items from an array?

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, mpmedialibrary

My app is not correctly displaying all of the items in my array. What is causing this to happen?

```
    var songamount = ["Refresh Page"]
    var songImageAmount = [MPMediaItemArtwork]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            let myPlaylistQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
            let playlists = myPlaylistQuery.collections
            self.songamount.remove(at: 0)
            for playlist in playlists! {
                print(playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)!)

                let songs = playlist.items
                for song in songs {
                    let songTitle = song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
                    let songImage = song.artwork
                    self.songamount.append(songTitle as! String)
                    self.songImageAmount.append(songImage!)
                    print("\t\t", songTitle!)

            }
            print(self.songamount)
            print("Song Amount:\(self.songamount.count)")
            print("Image Amount: \(self.songImageAmount.count)")


            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songamount.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LibraryCell", for: indexPath) as! LibraryCell
        cell.LibraryTitle.text = songamount[indexPath.row]
        //cell.LibraryImage.image = songImageAmount[indexPath.row]
        print(indexPath)

        return cell

    }
}
```

This is my code to show all the songs in a users Itunes library but it is only displaying 20 items from the array in the tableView.

Update- I have got it to correctly make a list of all my songs but it is only showing 33 of them in the list. Here is the updated code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TextDebug: UILabel!

    var songamount = ["Please Reload View"]
    var songImageAmount = [MPMediaItemArtwork]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            let mySongQuery = MPMediaQuery.songs()
            let songs = mySongQuery.collections
            self.songamount.remove(at: 0)
            for song in songs! {
                print(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)

                let songs = song.items
                for song in songs {
                    let songTitle = song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
                    //let songImage = song.artwork
                    self.songamount.append(songTitle as! String)
                    //self.songImageAmount.append(songImage!)
                    print("\t\t", songTitle!)

            }
            print(self.songamount)
            print("Song Amount:\(self.songamount.count)")
            //print("Image Amount: \(self.songImageAmount.count)")


            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songamount.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LibraryCell", for: indexPath) as! LibraryCell
        cell.LibraryTitle.text = songamount[indexPath.row]
        //cell.LibraryImage.image = songImageAmount[indexPath.row]
        let sections: Int = tableView.numberOfSections
        var rows: Int = 0

        for i in 0..<sections {
            rows += tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
            TextDebug.text = "\(rows)"
        }


        return cell

    }
```

Comment: What does `songamount.count` return?

Comment: @Koen It returns 472, which is actually over the amount of songs I have in my library for some reason. I am looking into this now

Comment: Make sure you reload the table view (on the main queue) after you finish updating the data model.

Comment: And you need to check the value of `status` in the `requestAuthorization` completion block. You should only attempt to access the songs if the status is `.authorized`.

Comment: @rmaddy I already run the .authorized code in an earlier section of the app which can not be passed unless access is authorized

Comment: Then why call `requestAuthorization` here?

Comment: Instead of editing your question with "solved", post a proper answer below showing your actual solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to add `tableView.reloadData()` to the end of `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: No, the solution is to call `reloadData()` just after the end of the `for` loop, inside the completion block.

Comment: @rmaddy What I did worked so It was the solution for me, that could also work but not what I did.

Comment: Calling `reloadData` after the asynchronous completion handler will likely not work under most conditions.